# c program to calculate multiples in interval

Tags: c

How to write a program that calculates the multiples of 7 between 21 and 210 inclusive?
This is an incorrect example:

*finding multiples of 7*

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int multiple;
int sum;
int i=0;
int j=0;
int sum1,sum2;


for (i=1;i>=21;i++){
    printf(i);
    sum1=i+sum1;

    for(j=1;j<=210;j++){
        printf(j);
        sum2=j+sum2;
    }
}
sum=sum1+sum2;
printf("sum",sum);
 }
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want multiple of seven like 7 * 1 =7 , 7 * 2= 14 ......... 7* 30= 201; .. then use simple for loop for(int i=0;i<30;i++) {sum = sum + 7 * i}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define lower and upper limit as `n1` and `n2` with 21 and 210 respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1,n2;
    n1=21;
    n2=210;
    while(n1<=n2)
    {
        if(n1%7==0)
            printf("%d ",n1);
        n1=n1+1;
    }
}
```

Tested code on Code Chef -  https://www.codechef.com/ide

Output:

21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 91 98 105 112 119 126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196 203 210

Comment: In this code, it's not critical, but you could use a preliminary loop incrementing `n1` by `1` until it is a multiple of the divisor (`7` in this example — interesting that you didn't make that a parameter too).  Then you can print the (possibly incremented) `n1` and proceed by adding the divisor each time.  (`int n3 = 7; while (n1 % n3 != 0) n1++; while (n1 <= n2) { printf("%d ", n1); n1 += n3; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;

    //set your lower bound and upper bound
    for (i = 21 ; i <= 210 ; i++)
    {
        if ( (i % 7) == 0 )
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    printf("total sum = %d \n",sum);
 }
```